# Failing to cache achievements

Tags: unreal-engine4, oculusquest

I'm currently working on a game for Oculus Quest, using Unreal 4.26.

Following [this](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unreal/ps-setup/) and [this](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unreal/ps-achievements/) articles from Oculus Developer portal I've set up Oculus Online Subsystem in my project, and **it successfully checks for App Entitlement at startup**.

Nevertheless, I'm having troubles when it comes to Achievements handling. **My Cache Achievements node always return Failure**. Of course, if I try to write any Achievement Progress, it fails as well.

My DefaultEngine.ini has the following code:

```
[OnlineSubsystem]
DefaultPlatformService=Oculus
bHasVoiceEnabled=true

[OnlineSubsystemOculus]
bEnabled=true
OculusAppId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And I also added a Config/Android/AndroidEngine.ini file with the following:

```
[OnlineSubsystem]
DefaultPlatformService=Oculus
```

Despite this last thing, when I build my app, a /Saved/Temp/Android/Engine/Config/Android/AndroidEngine.ini file gets created with the following:

```
[OnlineSubsystem]
DefaultPlatformService=GooglePlay
```

I don't know if this is what may be causing my Achievement Caching to fail.

Does anyone have a clue on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working.

It seems that nothing was wrong with my project or configuration, but Achievements refused to work, don't know why.

At the end, I installed [OculusPlatformBP](https://github.com/InnerLoopLLC/OculusPlatformBP) in my project and, via its API, it worked like a charm.